# Getting Result of Status ID from Bridge Table for Each Item

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, multidimensional-array

I'm hoping you can help out with this problem I'm having.

I have a bridge table called 'events_delegates_bridge' which has 3 fields, 'id', 'event_id' and 'delegate_id'.

I also have tables called 'delegates' and 'events'.

I also have a table called 'delegate_status', which has two fields, 'id' and 'delegate_status'.

Each delegate has a status attached to them which can either be 'Provisional', 'Confirmed' or 'Resit'.

Tables

```
Table : events_delegates_bridge |   Columns : id , event_id , delegate_id
Table : delegates
Table : events
Table : delegate_status | Columns : id , delegate_status (Provisional , Confirmed , Resit)
```

Now, in my 'delegates_model' class, I am joining the tables 'delegates', 'delegate_status' and 'events_delegates_bridge' based on the associated 'id', delegate_status 'id' and 'delegate_id' in each respective table, like so:

```
class Delegate_Model extends CI_Model {

    public function get_delegates() {

        $this->db->select( '*' );
        $this->db->from( 'delegates' );
        $this->db->from( 'delegate_status' );
        $this->db->join( 'events_delegates_bridge', 'events_delegates_bridge.delegate_id = delegates.id AND delegate_status.id = delegates.delegate_status_id', 'inner' );
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();

    }

}
```

I then use a 'delegates_helper' set of functions to do various things, one of them is to generate a 'status_id' variable for each delegate containing their status id so I can associate that with one of three columns in a HTML table, total provisional delegates and their names, total confirmed delegates and their names and finally total resits and their names.

I am generating the status id like so:

```
function get_status_id( $delegates ) {

    foreach ( $delegates as $delegate ) {

        switch( $delegate->delegate_status ) {

            case 'Provisional':
                $status = 'Provisional';
                $status_id = 1;
            break;

            case 'Confirmed':
                $status = 'Confirmed';
                $status_id = 2;
            break;

            case 'Resit':
                $status = 'Resit';
                $status_id = 3;
            break;

            default:
                $status = 'Confirmed';
                $status_id = 2;
            break;

        }

    }

    return $status_id;

}
```

At the moment, each $delegate->delegate_status has all of the records for every delegate I think, this is making this function always show as 'Provisional', 1.

I'm aware that I'm not approaching this problem correctly and would appreciate some guidance on how to do what I need. Thanks guys.

**NOTE: EDIT**

OK, so the desired output I am after is to get every delegate for a specific event and separate those delegates out in to 3 columns in a HTML for each event showing provisional delegates, confirmed delegates and those delegates taking resits.

Tables

```
Table : events_delegates_bridge |   Columns : id , event_id , delegate_id
Table : delegates       | Columns : id, delegate_first_name, delegate_last_name, delegate_status_id (1, 2, 3)
Table : events          | Columns : id, event_name, event_start_date
Table : delegate_status | Columns : id , delegate_status (Provisional , Confirmed , Resit)
```

I'm using the followoing functions to generate the HTML for the events table. This information (the variables) are then used in the view to populate a bootstrap popover:

```
function delegate_status_total( $delegates, $event ) {

    $status_id = get_status_id( $delegates );

    $current_event_id = $event->id;

    foreach ( $delegates as $delegate ) {

        if( $delegate->event_id == $current_event_id ) {

            if( $delegate->delegate_status_id == $status_id ) {

                $delegate_status_ids[] = $delegate->delegate_status_id;

                $delegate_total = count( $delegate_status_ids );

            }

        }

    }

    return $delegate_total;

}

function delegate_info( $delegates, $event ) {

    $delegate_total = delegate_status_total( $delegates, $event );

    $status_id = get_status_id( $delegates );

    $current_event_id = $event->id;

    $delegate_info = "There are currently a total of $delegate_total Provisional delegates booked on this event.<br /><br />";

    $delegate_info .= '<ul>';

        foreach ( $delegates as $delegate ) {

                if( $delegate->event_id == $current_event_id ) {

                    if( $delegate->delegate_status_id == $status_id ) {

                        $delegate_info .= '<li>';

                            $delegate_info .= $delegate->delegate_first_name . ' ' . $delegate->delegate_last_name;

                        $delegate_info .= '</li>';

                    }

                }

        }
    $delegate_info .= '</ul>';

    return $delegate_info;

}
```

**EDIT**

So, when a do the foreach loop on the $delegates object and then set the $status_id, it's setting only the first id of the first delegate. If I var_dump() the $delegate->delegate_status_id within the foreach loop like so:

```
foreach ( $delegates as $delegate ) {

    if( $delegate->event_id == $current_event_id ) {

        prettyDump( $delegate->delegate_status_id );

    }

}
```

it outputs every delegate_status_id within each $delegate item as you'd expect:

```
string(1) "1"
string(1) "2"
string(1) "3"
string(1) "1"
```

So each $delegate contains the delegate_status_ids of every other delegate, and because the first one is 'Provisional', 1 all of the $status_id variables for each delegate are set to that.

There must be a way of retrieving only the specific delegate status id?

Comment: My advice is to put the PHP aside and experiment with pure SQL until it gives you the results you need. Once you have a query that returns the data you want, you should be able to do away with the case statement.

Comment: instead of this put some sameple data and desired output. This all can be handeled with a single sql query without php loops and conditions

Comment: I already have the data from the delegate_model that contains everything for each delegate.

Comment: OK guys, I've added more information about the required output. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have done it with a single query without loops. Here is an example

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM events_delegates_bridge AS edb
  LEFT JOIN events AS e
    ON e.id = edb.event_id
  LEFT JOIN delegates AS d
    ON d.id = edb.delegate_id
  LEFT JOIN delegate_status AS ds
    ON ds.id = d.delegate_status_id
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff78a/1)

Output

```
id  event_id    delegate_id id  event_name  event_start_date    id  delegate_first_name delegate_last_name  delegate_status_id  id  delegate_status
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   1           1           1   A           2013-03-31          1   Ralf                Rudolph             1                   1   Provisional
2   2           2           2   B           2013-03-31          2   Clark               Filsh               2                   2   Confirmed
3   3           3           3   C           2013-03-31          3   Neil                Johnson             3                   3   Resit
```

If you need only specific columns use tablename.column instead of * in query

Comment: Yes, I did indeed go with your approach. Using active record, I cleaned up the data coming back from the database by using specific queries for specific things and I've now managed to get it all working, rather than using one large query. Thanks man.